# How to delete the last char in a text file in c?

Tags: c

I want to delete the last char of a text file. I have a code that saves strings and I need to delete only the last '\n'.

I already tried to do:

```
fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
fputs("", fp);
```

Here's the full code:

```
void saveGIF(FrameNode** head)
{
    FILE* fp = 0;
    FrameNode* curr = *head;
    int i = 1;
    int howManyFrames = framesInList(head);
    char c = 0;
    char filePath[SIZE] = { 0 };

    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nothing to save, add more frames and than save\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Where to save the project? enter a full path and file name\n");
        getchar();
        myFgets(filePath, SIZE);
        fp = fopen(filePath, "w+");
        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            while (curr)
            {
                fprintf(fp, "%s %d %s\n", curr->frame->name, curr->frame->duration, curr->frame->path);
                curr = curr->next;
                i++;
            }
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
            fputs("", fp);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error! canot create file\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to write a whole new file, although it would seem like there should be a reasonable solution to this. I doubt it will involve `fputs` if it does exist though.

Comment: Platform?  On POSIX, the answer is [`ftruncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html)
or [`truncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/truncate.html).  On Windows, the answer will probably be different.

Comment: The second top scoring answer in the duplicate covers Windows and has some comments related to Win64 etc.  My answer there also has links — to MSDN and to the other answer.

Comment: You could overwrite the final newline with a blank using `fputs(" ", fp)`, but writing an empty string doesn't change the file content.  You could also use `fwrite()` to write a null byte over the newline.  However, neither of those shortens the file, unlike `truncate()` and its related functions.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Text files should always end with a newline character.

Comment: @user3121023 thank you so mach your answer is perfact

Answer (score 2):

In ISO C, the only way to do this is to write out a new copy of the entire file under a temporary name, and then use `rename` to change its name to the old name.  There is no way to shorten a file in place.  (If you are on Windows you may have to `remove` the old name before `rename` will work.)

POSIX adds the `ftruncate` operation which can be used to make a file shorter (or longer) in place.  Most common operating systems support POSIX features, but Windows doesn't.  Depending on which compiler you have on Windows, you might still have a function named `ftruncate`, though, because the C runtime on Windows often tries to fake a subset of POSIX functionality -- many of those fakes are unreliable, but I confess I don't see how one could screw up `ftruncate` given that Windows proper *does* have an equivalent primitive operation, it just has a different name (`SetEndOfFile`).